# jquery dynamically added checkbox .attr("checked",true) not working

Tags: jquery

Based on some data I'm cloning a div with a checkbox and check it if the data value is "True" then append to a target div.

using jquery 1.5.2

IE8 works in compatibility mode, doesn't work otherwise.
FF doesn't work.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {          
            // test data
            var data = [{ "CB": "True" }, { "CB": "False"}];

            var theClone = $("#clone").clone(true);
            var temp = "";

            if (data !== null) {
                $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                    var cb = theClone.find('.cbClass');

                    if (d.CB === "True") { 
                        //cb.attr("checked","checked"); //doesn't work
                        //cb.val(true); //doesn't work
                        //cb.attr("checked", true); //doesn't work

                    }

                    temp += theClone.html();
                });
            }
            $("#target").append(temp);    
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="target">
    <div id="clone" class="cloneClass" style="display:none">
    <div class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" class="cbClass" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry about the changes wanted to make sure i was clear ;]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out, it appears that using `.attr("checked", "checked")` does not effect the html, try using the direct javascript method `setAttribute` and `removeAttribute`

```
$.each(data, function(i, d) {
    var cb = theClone.find('.cbClass');
    if (d.CB === "True") {
        cb.get()[0].setAttribute("checked", "checked");
    }
    else{
         cb.get()[0].removeAttribute("checked");
    }
    temp += theClone.html();
});
```

Also notice since you are always working with `theClone` you need to use `removeAttribute` since the previous iteration modified the element.

[**Code example on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/q88gw/)

**Update**

If you deal directly with jQuery objects it appears it will work in IE9, chrome, FF, and IE compatibility mode.

```
var temp = [];

if (data !== null) {
    $.each(data, function(i, d) {
        var theClone = $("#clone div").clone(true);
        var cb = theClone.find('.cbClass');
        if (d.CB === "True") {
            cb.attr("checked", "checked");
        }
        temp.push(theClone);
    });
}

$.each(temp, function(i, item) {
    $("body").append(item);
});
```

**[Code example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/q88gw/2/)**

Comment: this works in IE8 and FF.  But not in IE8 compatibility mode, all checkboxes get checked.  So weird!

Comment: @user331884 see update, adjusted to use just jQuery objects instead of `html()` appears to work in IE, FF, Chrome, and Compatibility mode.

Comment: instead of '.attr' you can use '.prop' that one more effective way [link](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 4):

In place of `.attr`, use `.prop` jquery method (included in [jquery1.6](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/10/jquery-1-6-1-rc-1-released/)).Here is detailed discussion [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr).

Answer (score 2):

The attribute `checked` doesn't have a value of "true", and instead needs to be `checked` as well.  Such is in accordance with the XHTML standard, which your page doctype is probably set to.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('.foo').attr('checked', 'checked');
$('.foo').removeAttr('checked')
```

As a side note, you might want to take a look at and refactor your JSON there.  As a rule of thumb as well, whenever you've got a boolean test and one of your params is a boolean itself, you need to refactor.

Edit:
This issue is caused by the differing implementations by browser of `.innerHTML`.  You have a further issue where you're only setting the clone source to true and never the opposite, thus once one checkbox is set to true, they all will be (which is the issue in the other posted answer).  You need to refactor to something like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {          
            // test data
            var data = [{ "CB": "True" }, { "CB": "False"}];

            var temp = "";
            if (data !== null) {
                $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                    var theClone = $("#clone").clone(true);
                    var cb = theClone.find('.cbClass');
                    if (d.CB === "True") { 
                        theClone.find('input').attr("checked","checked"); 
                    }
                    $("#target").append(theClone);  
                });
            }

        });
    </script>
```

WARNING: doing duplicate appends like this will have performance issues over large collections.  If it's more than two, refactor further. :)

Comment: I hear you on the JSON data but it's what I'm stuck working with.  They're string literals "True"/"False".  Back to .attr('checked','checked') it's not working for me in IE8 or FF.  But works in IE8 compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

For me, using .attr was working in chrome but not in IE, and .prop seemed to have the same issue.

What I begrudgingly went with in the end was to physically click the option...

```
$('#RadioButtonIdToSelect').click();
```