# jquery 1.9 won't check radio in IE9 / xhtml

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, radio-button

I am trying to get IE9 to acnowledge that a radio button group has an option checked, set via script. In my script I want the first option to be checked. Doesn't work in IE9 with compatibility mode ON on a xhtml doctype (required configuration).

```
var $list = jQuery("#my-radio-container");
jQuery(":radio",$list).each(function (ind,el) {
var $elm = jQuery(el);
$elm.addClass("ui-widget-content");
if (ind == 0) {
    $elm.addClass("ui-state-active")
    .get()[0].setAttribute("checked", "checked")
});
```

I've tried all the usual combos:

```
$elm.attr('checked', 'checked');
$elm.prop('checked', 'checked');
$elm.attr('checked', true);
```

as well as the more unusual ones:

```
 $elm.get()[0].setAttribute("checked", "checked")
```

which looks like it should work - if you check the innerHTML of `$list` then it shows that the object has `CHECKED="checked"` in it, so you would think that it would be selected? But perfoming a form post shows that no data is submitted for the radio button  (clicking the button, rather than setting it in script, reveals the same outer html and the form DOES post with the value).

Reverting back to this doesn't even work, which is odd:

```
 document.forms[0].elements[jQuery(":radio",$list).filter(":first").attr("name")].value = jQuery(":radio",$list).filter(":first").attr("value");

 // which works out like this:
 document.forms[0].myradio.value="1";
```

1. I'm waiting till document ready.
2. I have googled this. I've been trying [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570455/jquery-dynamically-added-checkbox-attrchecked-true-not-working) techniques suggested in various articles, and just because I only linked to one article doesn't mean I haven't just closed tabs on about 20 others.
3. I've checked what my element is, and yes it's an input type=radio tag, not the label for it or something stupid.

`IE9 doesn't want to let me set a radio button check state through code.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.prop("checked", true)` to check and `.prop("checked", false)` to uncheck. The Migrate plugin should have warned about `.attr(..., true)`

Comment: looks like in my frustration I had been using .prop() incorrectly; the correct usage fixes the problem; cheers! (and phew: I didn't have to use the hidden-field hack!)

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues before which I've worked around by declaring a hidden field before the input field (with the same name) and setting the value to 0, which ensures there is a field to post / modify. It's a long shot but has worked for me in the past.

Comment: ok, sounds horrible but this IS internet explorer so that's par for the course. Still tinkering trying to work out a reason but this might have to do..