# jquery dynamically checked chexbox

Tags: jquery, dynamic, checkbox

I have problem with checkbox. When i choose checkbox, my script mark other checkbox. Ex: If I clicked on the option 1, the script will mark options 101 and vice versa(unmark-unselect).

My code, work once. That is to say: I'm marking field 1, the script selects the 101, later  I'm unmarking field 1, the script unselects the 101. Now I want again marking field 1... the skrypt doing nothing.

```
        var e=$('.serwis_check').eq(i).attr('class').split(/\s+/);


        $.each(e,function(index, item){

            if(item!='serwis_check')
            {
                    if($('.'+item).is(':checked')) {
                        $('#'+item).attr('checked', true);

                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $('#'+item).attr('checked', false);
                    }
            }

        });
```

I tried: [jquery dynamically added checkbox .attr("checked",true) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570455/jquery-dynamically-added-checkbox-attrchecked-true-not-working)

Comment: use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery?rq=1

Comment: If that doesn't work, show us your HTML

Comment: Arun P Johny - right. Work ;-)